# Fatal error on login

Tags: login, session

Hi I just started my journey in linux world and it's a bunch of installation now: starting with Linux Mint 17.02 a couple of times and one on an old HDD before that, and now I moved on Ubuntu Studio 14.04 for unknown issues with Kde Plasma or some related settings misbehavior.

Any way my observations of the mistakes I've made and the errors I get make me believe it is mostly something that KdeConnect is not doing very well.
I get the same message on login when crash is about to happen : **Invalid Action : -session**

Then on the next reboot or a couple further no session is loaded after entering password. Just the background image of the desktop is ok and mouse is moving.
May or may not be caused by changing the permissions of the /root folder and contents, and if it so is there a way to fix it to default from grub terminal as I got no further access?

The installation is no problem it just hard to get the files from the system before formatting the drive is driving me crazy.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE

Well,

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoupdate
```

gives this output:

```
sudo: error in /etc/sudo.conf, line 0 while loading plugin 'sudoers_policy'
sudo: /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so must be only be writable by owner
sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugins
```

so three things I thought:

1. run the comand as root with `su` may do the trick
2. Probably sudoers file change I've made by `sudo visudo` and adding 'Default        !authenticate' to loose some excessive prompts
3. changing the '/root' folder permissions through nautilus from only root user read/write to group as well so I can get access to session logs giving me a session error message on logon

   ~$ su
   Password:
   su: Authentication failure

seems to me that I messed it up pretty much :D though is there a way to fix that

Comment: Wasn't sure where to add the longer and more accurate answer

Comment: Excuse me though

Comment: If not removed pls comment the 'answer'

Comment: Hi lsnd, please remove solved from the title and the solution from the question. Answer your own question and accept the answer to indicate that it is solved.

Comment: Yes i will but unfortunately  have been banned from posting answers so if i am to do that it will take a wile until i have my ban lifted

Answer (score 0):

I believe a fatal error with the graphics drivers. On the login page, press Ctrl+Alt+F1. Thus will open a terminal. Type "sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall" (without the inverted commas.) and a large process should begin. When finished, press Ctrl+Alt+F7 and you should soon return to the login page. Reboot the computer. You might notice a slight difference with the Ubuntu logo on boot. No need to fear, this is normal. You should now be able to log in. :)

Comment: Well,

    sudo ubuntu-drivers autoupdate

gives this output:

    sudo: error in /etc/sudo.conf, line 0 while loading plugin 'sudoers_policy'
    sudo: /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so must be only be writable by owner
    sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugins

Comment: so three things I thought:

 1. run the comand as root with `su` may do the trick
 2. Probably sudoers file change I've made by `sudo visudo` and adding 'Default        !authenticate' to loose some excessive prompts 
 3. changing the '/root' folder permissions through nautilus from only root user read/write to group as well so I can get access to session logs giving me a session error message on logon

Comment: ~$ su
    Password:
    su: Authentication failure


seems to me that I messed it up pretty much :D though is there a way to fix that

Comment: If you are unable to auto-install graphics drivers, then we have some BIG stuff messed up, and I am afraid I can assist you no further. I apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: Wait a minute... did you type "sudo ubuntu-drivers autoupdate"? It's "sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall"!

Comment: But no need to try, looks like the sudo policy is completely destroyed.

Comment: Thanks. I had to reinstall anyway for a few urgent tasks so my problem is literally gone :) . But I'm pretty sure it was because of the permissions mess, in addition of the sudoers file modification.

Comment: Good to hear, although you are correct: the permissions file for sudo users was completely messed up or deleted. **Thanks for the feedback! :)**